# Git: done work on master and need it in a branch

Tags: git, github

I have made some changes to the master branch of a repository.  I've not added those files to master, nor checked them in (neither locally nor to the remote master branch).  I then realised that I should have done this work on a new branch.  What is the quickest and best way to apply those changes to a branch?  Would I be able to stash the changes, create a branch and then apply those changes to the stash or can you only apply a stash to the branch you created it on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply stashed changes to any branch, not just the one you created them on. However, you may not even need to do that. If you're changes don't cause any conflicts you and you haven't checked them in at all, you can just create a branch and check it out, then commit your changes.

```
% git checkout master
# edit some files...
% git checkout -b new_branch
% git add .
% git commit
```

Comment: will those changes no longer appear on master then?

Comment: that's correct, as long as (as you said) you haven't checked them in to master already.

Comment: +1 Cool thanks.  I love the way Git is designed.  So glad I'm not using SVN anymore.

Answer (score 1):

1. stash
2. create/change branch
3. stash pop
4. commit
5. push
6. enjoy

and nope, stash is in a parallel dimension, it's not associated to a particular branch or remote. It is associated with your working copy so you can even switch remotes and keep the stash.

BTW you can stash several times, then use it as a LIFO stack.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are high you don't even need to stash, honestly.  If you haven't committed anything and you just want to branch from where you currently are on master, then you can just

```
git checkout -b newBranch
git commit
```

That is, if you don't have the changes currently on master, there isn't much to worry about.  If you need your branch to be based on an older master, then it might be needed, but if it is just the latest master, you should be good to go.